# How to get all the solutions for the equation $X^Y-Z^X=X^X$

Tags: logarithms

I tried to find all solutions for this equation:

$$X^Y-Z^X=X^X$$

My math is not that good, I thought I could do it with logarithms but this did not work. I already have one set of solutions:

$$X=3,\
Y=5,\
Z=6$$

but I what to know if there are more solutions to this equation and how I should tackle such problem

Comment: Are all three supposed to be integers?

Comment: $X$ could be $1$, $Z$ could be $0$, and then $Y$ could be anything.

Comment: @alex.jordan They don't have to be integers

Comment: More generally, you can solve the equation for $Y$, and obtain the solutions: $X,Z$ abitrar, $Y = \frac{\ln(X^ X + Z^X)}{\ln(X)}$

Answer (score 2):

I guess $x,y,z$ are all positive integers. So, we have:
$$x^y-x^x=z^x \implies x^x(x^{y-x}-1)=z^x$$
We have $y>x$ and $x \mid z$. Let $a=y-x$ and $b=\frac{z}{x}$. Thus:
$$x^a-1=b^x$$
Thus, we must either have:

Case 1: $a,x>1$

By Mihailescu's theorem, we will have $(x,a,b)=(3,2,2)$. This gives us $(x,y,z)=(3,5,6)$.

Case 2: $a=1$

$$2^x>x-1=b^x \implies b=1 \implies x=2 \implies (x,y,z)=(2,3,2)$$

Case 3: $x=1$

$$b^x=1-1=0 \implies b=0 \implies z=0$$
However, this is not possible as $x,y,z$ are positive integers.

Thus, for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$, the only solutions are $(x,y,z)=(3,5,6),(2,3,2)$.

---

If $x,y,z$ are any reals, we can just directly have:
$$y=\log_{x}(x^x+z^x)= \frac{\ln(x^x+z^x)}{\ln(x)}$$

Comment: Yes I did. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Edit done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make $Y$ the subject, i.e.

\begin{align}
X^Y-Z^X = X^X &\Rightarrow X^Y = X^X + Z^X \Rightarrow Y\ln (X) = \ln\left(X^X + Z^X\right)\\
&\Rightarrow Y = \frac{\ln\left(X^X + Z^X\right)}{\ln (X)}
\end{align}

Now if you plug in values of $X$ and $Z$, it will provide the corresponding $Y$ value that satisfies your equation.